# Using .val().length != 0 to show textbox

Tags: jquery, display, preventdefault, is-empty

I am working with a survey, with a note section after every question. Notes should only come up after pressing End or F10 the first time. After skipping ahead to question 2, and then going back to question 1, the note section for question 1 should again be hidden if there were no notes.

However, if there is any writing in the notes section at all, I want them to remain visible after returning to question 1 from question 2.

I am trying to accomplish this by using .val().length != 0 to display the notes if there is even one character written. I'm not sure if my issue here is with .val().length or with my preventDefault command, I want to prevent the default action which in this case is to not display the notes.

```
<style>
#[% QuestionName() %]_div {display:none}
</style> 

<script>

$(document).keydown(checkNote);
function checkNote(f){
f = f || window.event;
if (f.keyCode == '121' || f.keyCode == '35'){
    f.preventDefault(f);
    $("#[% QuestionName() %]_div").css('display', 'block');
    }
}

function displaynote(d){
    d = d || window.event;
    if  ($("#[% QuestionName() %]_div").val().length != 0) {
        d.preventDefault(d);
        $("#[% QuestionName() %]_div").css('display', 'block');  
        }
      }
<script>
```

If somebody could tell me where my issue might be or provide an alternative to 
.val().length != 0 if that's the problem, than that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: this will compare value length, are you sure you don't want just val or just length?:

Comment: Would val work better? Is val for numbers only or also letters? As long as there is even one character in the box, letter or number, I want it to show.  I also tried val and it didn't do what I needed it to do, so maybe the problem is somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Val retrieves the value of the dom element, so it can return a string or int, and perhaps haha try console logging the val

Answer (score 2):

Is the element `#[% QuestionName() %]_div` an input?

`$(...).val()` works only for input elements (if you call the function on, say, a `div`, it will always return an empty string).

If it's a `div` you are working with, you could use `$(...).text()` or `$(...).html()` to retrieve its content.

Comment: Thankyou, that is helpful to know that $(...).val() only works for input elements. I tried .text() and .html to use with the div, but that didn't work, although I may have been using them the wrong way. I tried to get the input  `var $input1; $('#[% QuestionName() %]').focus(function() {` `$input1 = $(this); }); `  `if ($input1.val().length != 0)`  and insert it in here, but I haven't been able to get that to work – JakeHammond 6 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out what the problem was, there were a few of them. I moved the  displaynote function into a $(document).ready event to call it when the page was ready because it wasn't being called,

```
if ($('#[% QuestionName() %]').val().length != 0) {
```

I did use val().length but made sure I used a non div element, thanks for that Gabriel, then removed d = d || window.event; and d.preventDefault(d) because $(document).ready doesn't take any arguments